# Calling php scripts from windows phone 8 (C#)

Tags: c#, php, api, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a **windows phone 8** project. I want to connect to the database (MongoDB) which is hosted somewhere. **with out calling directly** to the database, I'm **calling through a php API**.(basically each operation has separate php scripts).

So I want to make C# send a request to PHP scripts running at the webserver and make PHP return data to windows phone application through internet.

Can anybody please tell me how to do this.

Please suggest any online links or tutorials or your own idea.

Comment: I would probably try to use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx)

Comment: @Jason I guess HttpClient is more suitable for REST APIs. but in my case API is not RESTful.

what is your opinion about HttpWebRequest,HttpWebResponse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Reference from here :  [How to call a PHP based web service in windows phone 8.](http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/windows-phone-development/how-to-call-a-php-based-web-service-in-windows-phone-8)